# Eclipse search for String.isEmpty()

Tags: java, eclipse, search

Is there any way in Eclipse (Java EE-juno-SR1) to search for all occurrences of `isEmpty()` that are invoked on string objects only?

For example,

I don't want the search to return `.isEmpty()` invoked like some `ArrayList.isEmpty()` in the search results. The best I have been able to do is search all occurrences of `isEmpty()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Ctrl Shift G`  - Find references in workspace, will catch the correct references only in Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

You can find who are calling your methods by the 'Call Hierarchy'

Right click on the method and say "Open Call Hierarchy"

cheers,
Saurav